# Using Functools (partial) to clear_widgets. will lambda work

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, kivy, partial, functools

Im still  a newbie. I get this error when I try to run the code. Can someone explain where the third argument is coming from. Is it from the loop? the code runs but the on_press  actually generates the error.

will lambda work for this.

this is the full code as edited with the correction given. The kivy is called for a `main.kv`

```
TypeError: clear_widgets() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

the error now is `TypeError: 'Tab' object is not subscriptable`

```
Python

class Main(MDApp):

def build(self):
    return

  def load_songs(self, storageLocation):
    songs = []
    #  dictionary = {}

    if Path('Books').is_dir():
        for filename in storageLocation.glob('**/*.wav'):
            songs.append(filename)
            # Create dictionary for each subfolder(Chapter)
        booksdir = [f for f in storageLocation.iterdir() if f.is_dir()]
        # for value, Bookfolders in enumerate(booksdir):
        for Bookfolders in booksdir:
            # if Bookfolders not in dictionary:
            # dictionary[Bookfolders] = []
            # dictionary[Bookfolders].append('yahoooooo')

            self.root.ids.Books.add_widget(
                OneLineListItem(text=str(Bookfolders),
                                on_press=lambda olli: self.root.ids.tabs.clear_widgets(Tab(Bookfolders)),
                                pos_hint={"center_x": 1, "center_y": 1},
                                on_release=partial(self.root.ids.tabs.add_widget,
                                                   Tab(title=str(Bookfolders)))))
            

    return songs


Main().run()




kivy

MDNavigationLayout:
    ScreenManager:
       Screen:
        #BooksScreen:
        #ChapterScreen:

        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            MDToolbar:
                title: "Chapters"
                font_style: "Caption"
                elevation:8
                left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
                Widget:

            MDTabs:
                id: tabs

        MDScreen
            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                MDList
                    id: Books

    #Options menu
MDNavigationDrawer:
    id: nav_drawer
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: "8dp"
        spacing: "8dp"

<Tab>
MDList:
    MDBoxLayout:
        adaptive_height: True
        MDLabel:
            id: label
            text: "Tab 0" #Tab Text
            halign: "center"


        MDFlatButton:
            text: "ADD TAB"
            on_release: app.add_tab()


        MDFlatButton:
            text: "REMOVE LAST TAB"
            on_release: app.remove_tab()

        MDFlatButton:
            text: "GET TAB LIST"
            on_release: app.get_tab_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `on_press` callback adds the source of the `on_press` event to the specified callback, creating a third argument. You can handle that third argument using `lambda` like this:

```
on_press= lambda olli: self.root.ids.tabs.clear_widgets(Tab)
```

The `olli` is the `OneLineListItem` instance that is the source of the `press` event, and is discarded by the `lambda` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though I still get a similar error `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: Also I am removing a `Tab` not a `OneLineListItem` could this be the reason for the error.

Comment: Cannot tell any more without seeing more of your code. But I notice you are using `Tab` as a classname in one place and passing it to `clear_widgets()` in another. The `clear_widgets()` method of `Widget` does not accept a classname as an argument.

Comment: `@John Anderson` I did some updates to the question, added the relevant code

Comment: I don't understand your argument to the `clear_widgets()` method. Try not passing any arguments to that method. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.clear_widgets).